# T-test unknown or known standard deviation?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, descriptive-statistics

One week ago I performed the following two experiments:
1) I made a tensile test on 30 steel wires. These wires have not been through a surface treatment. The maximum load is (in average) 28 Newton, with a standard deviation of 3,54 N.

2) I made a tensile test on 30 steel wires. These wires have BEEN through a surface treatment. The maximum load is (in average) 25 Newton, with a standard deviation of 3,94 N.

I am about to do a statistical analysis of this experiment but I am in doubt whether I should use the Z test (known variance) or the T test (unknown variance)?
Which should I use and why?

Comment: Do you have *sample* information or *population* information about the standard deviation of tensile strength of treated and untreated wires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that maximum load measurements are nearly normal, and that
the answer to @Glen-b's question is that the means and standard deviations
are based, respectively, on two samples of size 30, you should do a
two-sample t test.

**Welch two-sample t test:** Presumably you want to know whether sample means of 28 and 25 are sufficiently different to show that the surface treatment has changed
the strength of the wire in the implied populations of untreated and treated wire. Formally, this is a test of $H_0: \mu_U = \mu_T$ against 
$H_a: \mu_U \ne \mu_T.$

Results for a Welch (separate-variances) t test from Minitab statistical
software are shown below:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       30  28.00   3.54     0.65
2       30  25.00   3.94     0.72

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  3.000
95% CI for difference:  (1.064, 4.936)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
    T-Value = 3.10  P-Value = 0.003  DF = 57
```

Because the P-value is $0.003 < 0.05$ we reject $H_0$ at the 5% level
of significance, concluding that there is evidence that the treatment
makes a difference in wire strength.

**Pooled two-sample t test:** If you know from previous tests of this type
that the treatment is unlikely to change population variances, you could
do a pooled t test. Because the two samples are of the same size, the
$T$-statistic 3.10 is unchanged from the Welch test. The degrees of freedom would be DF $= 30+30-2 = 58$ instead of 57 in the printout above. The
P-value will still be small enough to reject at the 5% level.

**Z test:** If the standard deviations you provided are for the populations
(not for the two samples), then you could do a z test. The $Z$-statistic
exceeds 1.96 [in absolute value], so you would reject at the 5% level.

**One-sided tests:** If you had reason to suspect before seeing the data that the treatment leads to lower wire strength you might want to test
$H_0: \mu_U = \mu_T$ against 
$H_: \mu_U > \mu_T.$ The P-values for the one-sided Welch, pooled and 2-sample z tests would be half as large as for the corresponding two-sided tests discussed above.
You would still be able to reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance for
all three one-sided tests.

*Notes:* (a) If maximum load data are clearly not normal (highly skewed or with far outliers), you would need to do a non-parametric test. That would require having access to the actual observations, instead of just the means and variances. [I mention this possibility because I have run a few tests like this myself (something like 60 years ago), and my data were often distinctly non-normal, often with both low and high outliers.]

(b) It seems possible that this may be a textbook exercise instead of an actual industrial problem. In that case you can use what I have said to decide which kind of test you need to do, look in your text (or class notes or Online) to find the relevant formulas, show how to find the relevant test statistic, and show how to test at the 5% (or other) level of significance.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped me a lot!